# foreach statement cannot operate because does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I build a solution has 4 layers

- 1-One Solution (Data Access layer) has multi (DALs) from diffrent DBs.
- 2-Data Store(access all DALs).
- 3-Business Layer BL(haslogicalmethods)
- 4-Presentation layer (MVC4).

---

the problem is I want call a list search methods in DAL(Establishment) through BLL with Para Name to search it , and want to show the result in View in PL. 
**the EstController**

```
public ActionResult Index(string Name)
    {
        if (Name != null)
        {
            IList list = BLL.Establishment_Serv.getEstablishmentByName(Name.ToUpper());
            return View(list);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**and Est/Index View**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index" ,"Est",FormMethod.Get))
{
   <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("Name")  
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modleItem => item.Name)</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

and I face an error in foreach statement.And if there a best approach to doing it HINT me please.

Comment: I tried most solution and suggestion in this site , and nothing work with me.

Comment: if you list is null then you will get error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you put this inside your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourModel>
```

Comment: thinks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

if your list is null then you will get error

```
public ActionResult Index(string Name)
    {
        var list=new List<YourModelName>();
        if (Name != null)
        {
            list = BLL.Establishment_Serv.getEstablishmentByName(Name.ToUpper());
            return View(list);
        }
        else {
        return View(list);
}
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answer me, but what you mean by "Establishment_ServModel"?

Comment: of which model you are passing data to the view, give us the model name in the view.It should be like @model IEnumerable<YourModelName>